# prove $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

prove

$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$

what I have so far:

applying $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{n-r}$$
  applying Vandermonde's Identity and subtracting off the difference
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{n-r}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{n-r}-\binom{n}{0}\cdot\binom{n-1}{n}=\binom{2n-1}{n}-\binom{n}{0}\cdot\binom{n-1}{n}=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$$

Is this a valid proof? what happens when I try to evaluate $\binom{n}{0}\cdot\binom{n-1}{n}$? does this break the proof?
any alternate proofs or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: In general, a binomial coefficient $\binom mk$ with $k>m$ can safely be taken to be zero.

Comment: Algebraic solution : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757210/a-problem-on-binomial-theorem/2757224#2757224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this break the proof?

No, it is fine.  As Lord Shark the Unknown said, $\binom{n}{0}\cdot\binom{n-1}{n}=1\cdot 0$ since, by convention $\binom n m=0$ iff $m>n$.   (For instance, there are zero ways to select $n$ items from $n-1$, after all.)

> any alternate proofs or guidance is appreciated.

$\binom {2n-1}{n-1}$ counts the ways we may select $n-1$ items from a heap of $2n-1$.   Now suppose this heap was actually subdivided into two, one of size $n$ and the other of size $n-1$, so when selecting the $n-1$ items from these heaps, we do so by taking some of them (say, $r$) from the first and the rest from the other.   Count the distinct ways we can do this, thereby showing that ...
$\therefore \quad \dbinom{2n-1}{n-1}=\mathop{\huge \sum}\limits_{r=1}^n\dbinom n r\dbinom{n-1}{r-1}$

Comment: Equivalent to the "Heaps" method :  The co-efficient of  $X^n$ in the binomial expansion of $(1+X)^{2n-1}$ is $\binom {2n-1}{n}=\binom {2n-1}{n-1}.$ This is equal to the co-efficient of $X^n$ obtained from  the product of the  binomial expansions of $(1+X)^n$ and $(1+X)^{n-1}$, and this co-efficient  is the summation  given in the Q.

Comment: @Te55eract. Yes.  He has skipped a step, (as did I in my previous comment), namely that  $\binom {n-1}{n-r}=$ $\binom {n-1}{n-1-(n-r)}=$ $\binom {n-1}{r-1}.$